# Dynamically Supply Component To Redux Container

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a basic redux container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Renderer from '../components/renderers/AlphaRenderer/AlphaRenderer';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  ...
});

const RendererContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AlphaRenderer);

export default RendererContainer;
```

This exact same container is used with multiple React components - each component uses the same props and emits the same events, but other than that are very different from one-another. Rather than repeat the same container for each component, I would like a way to pass in the component to the container. The equivalent of:

```
<RendererContainer component={AlphaRenderer} />
<RendererContainer component={BetaRenderer} />
<RendererContainer component={CharlieRenderer} />
```

Is there a way to pass a component into a container at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obviously do something like

```
//just the connect function
const RendererContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

//react component 
const ReduxWrapperComponent = (props) => (return React.createElement(RendererContainer(props.component));)

or 
const ReduxWrapperComponent = (props) => (return <div>{RendererContainer(props.component)}</div>;)

//use it as 
//<ReduxWrapperComponent component={XYZ}/>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Returning the value of `connect()()` is not the same as returning the value of `connect()()` from a stateless react component.

Comment: Are you sure? I meant `connect()` not `connect()()`. `connect()` will return a fn

Comment: Pretty sure: Invariant Violation: ReduxWrapperComponent(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: Can you try printing the values, connect would return a fn, I suspect something else is wrong

Comment: This does work with the following modification - Instead of returning `RenderContainer(props.component)` you need to return `React.createElement(RendererContainer(props.component));`. If you update your answer I'll give you the win.

Comment: I think this is that same as wrapping in a div. Nevermind, good catch !